# In C++, calling a derived constructor creates a base object or not?

Tags: c++, derived

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base{
    private:
        int x;

    public:
        Base(int i){
            x = i;
        }

        void print(){
            cout<<x<<endl;
        }
};

class Derived: public Base{
    public:
        Base b;

    public:
        //the constructor of the derived class which contains the argument list of base class and the b
        Derived(int i, int j): Base(i), b(j)
        {}
      
};

int main(){
    Derived d(11, 22);
    d.print();
    d.b.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Why is the value of `b.x` 11, but the value of `d.b.x` is 22?

If the constructor of the base class initializes the int `x` in class `Base`, does a `Base` object exist?

In the argument list of the derived constructor, should there be one argument or two arguments when there is a `Base b` as a class member?

Comment: `Derived::b` is not `Derived::Base`

Comment: Yes, calling a derived constructor creates (constructs) a base object.  The construction of the base object occurs before the derived object's member variables are each constructed.

Answer (score 3):

The constructor of `Derived` uses its first argument (11) to initialize its base class `Base`, so the member `Derived.x` has the value 11. This is what is output by `d.print()`.

The constructor of `Derived` uses its second argument (22) to initialize its member `b` (whose type is `Base`). This is what is output by `d.b.print()`.

There are two `Base` objects here. `d` is a `Derived`, which is also a `Base`. The member `d.b` is a `Base` as well.

The argument list of the `Derived` constructor can be whatever you want it to be, depending on how you want to initialize any of its contents.

Comment: I was wondering that the Derived d contains a Base b, and Base b contains a int x, but the d.x is 11 and d.b.x is 22, which means they are not the same one x?

Comment: Correct. The `Base` that `Derived` has due to inheriting from `Base` is a separate and distinct `Base` from the `Base` that `Derived` has due to the member variable `Base b;`.

Comment: @pipi Each instance of `Base` has its own `x`. You have two instances of `Base` here, one called `d` and one called `b`. (Every instance of `Derived` is also an instance of `Base`.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz thx! I got it!

Answer (score 0):

The value of `i` is allocated to the variable `x` of the class `Derived`, and the value of `j` is allocated to the variable `x` of the object `b` declared in `Derived`. The `x` of `Derived` and the `x` of `b` are two different variables. The second argument is required if you want to allocate a value to `b`. You can call the constructor for `Base` explicitly as an alternative to using 2 arguments in the `Derived` constructor.

Comment: Would be good to break this answer up into multiple paragraphs, at least one for each question asked by the author.